# Surjection of $\text{Hom}(-,I)$ where $I$ is injective

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, injective-module

Let $I$ be an injective abelian group and $G\to H$ an injective morphism of groups, not necessarly abelian. If $G,H$ were abelian, then we would have a surjection
$$\text{Hom}(H,I)\to \text{Hom}(G,I).$$
Can we still say something about $\text{Hom}(H,I)\to \text{Hom}(G,I)$ if we do not assume that $G,H$ are abelian. Since $I$ is assumed to be abelian, this is the same as the morphism
$$\text{Hom}(H^{ab},I)\to \text{Hom}(G^{ab},I)$$
but the abelianization functor $(-)^{ab}$ is only right-exact, but not left-exact. We have a left exact sequence $0\to G\cap[H,H]/[G,G]\to G^{ab}\to H^{ab}$ which yields
$$\text{Hom}(H^{ab},I)\to \text{Hom}(G^{ab},I)\to \text{Hom}(G/G\cap[H,H],I)\to \text{Ext}^1(G^{ab},I)=0.$$
It is probably to much to hope for $\text{Hom}(G\cap[H,H]/[G,G],I)=0$, but are there "nice" things to assume make it true?

Comment: It is certainly too much to hope for. For example, take $I=\mathbb{Z}_{2^{\infty}}$, the Prufer $2$-group (divisible, hence injective), $G=S_5$, and $H=A_7$, and take the standard embedding $G\to H$. There is a nontrivial map $G\to I$, but there are no nontrivial maps $H\to I$, so not every map from $G$ can be extended to $H$.